# PHP Calculations inside string creation

Tags: php, string

I want to to create a string in php, but within the creation of the string I want to do a small calculation, here is an example of what I am trying but does not work.

```
$eggs = 2;

$breakfast = 'I ate '. $eggs-1 . ' eggs for breakfast today!';
```

Using PHP like this gives me a unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add brackets:

```
$breakfast = 'I ate '. ($eggs-1) . ' eggs for breakfast today!';
```